# Dynamic where clause in active record avoiding sql injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-injection

do you know how to build a dynamic query avoiding sql injection
?

```
property = 'foo'
value = 'bar'
SomeObject.where("#{property} > ?", value)
# works but permit sql inj
SomeObject.where(":property > :value", property: property, value: value)
# create select * from some_object where 'foo' > 'bar'
# and the 'foo' I need without the quotes
```

Comment: (I don't know Ruby) Why not, just before composing the request with your input, replacing all occurrences of `'` in the input by `''` (2 simple quotes, to escape them); and others changes of that kind before executing the request

Comment: @NatNgs sanitizing SQL (or other input) is actually quite complex and your aproach potentially misses other attack vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but secure way would be to whitelist the allowed property names:

```
PROPERTIES = ["foo", "bar", "baz"].freeze
def find_greater_than(property, value)
  raise "'#{property}' is not a valid property, only #{PROPERTIES.join(", ")} are allowed!" if !PROPERTIES.include?(property)
  SomeObject.where("#{property} > ?", value)
end
```

You can (as @engineersmnky pointed out) dynamically check for available columns:

```
raise "Some Message" if SomeObject.column_names.include?(property)
```

but I don't like this aproach as having columns searchable should be a decission, not automated.

Another aproach is to use the sanitizing provided by Rails.

```
def find_greater_than(property, value)
  sanitized_property = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_column_name(property)
  SomeObject.where("#{sanitized_property} > ?", value)
end
```

The quoting logic is implemented by the DB specific connection adapters.

Comment: - Error messages like "Hey...don't do this" aren't saying anything.
- Why not give the method a good name, rather than "do_something"?
- Eye candy: use `unless` instead of `if !` (that's probably preference)

Comment: @siegy22: eye candy i don't like unless. I think it should not exist:-)
I'll updated the response for the rest of your comments though it is difficult to give meaningful method names when the context is unknown...

Comment: I agree that searchable columns should be a declaration although maintaining the congruence between the database and a frozen `Array` could become more cumbersome than it is worth. Also tisk tisk for liking ruby and hating `unless`. I find its readability far superior to "I will do this if not you are true"

Comment: @engineersmnky I hear from a lot of german speaking Rubyists that they don't like `unless`....

Comment: *Warum das?* I am going to have to assume that has something to do with the fact that *wenn nicht* (literally "if not") is the common terminology for the english word unless

Comment: Ich weiss es nicht. The only explanation I came up with is the same as you have: "if not" translates to "wenn nicht"/"falls nicht". 
Also I'm coming (though this is a long time ago) from languages that do not know "unless".

Answer (score 3):

```
SomeObject.where(
  "#{SomeObject.connection.quote_column_name(property)} > :value", 
  value: value
)
```

**UPDATE**

Example 1 (trying to end the statement and inject a new one):

```
property = '; DROP TABLE users; --'
User.where("#{User.connection.quote_column_name(property)} > :value", value: 3)
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("; DROP TABLE users; --" > 3)
```

Example 2 (trying to end the column name quote):

```
property = '"; DELETE FROM users;--'
User.where("#{User.connection.quote_column_name(property)} > :value", value: 3)
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("""; DELETE FROM users;--" > 3)
```

Comment: Can you add a gist to prove that this works as expected?

Comment: @siegy22 what do you mean exactly? Should I post some example SQL output?

Comment: Yeah, just try to do an SQL injection

Comment: @siegy22 Added examples with the resulting output.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of your use case but `arel` can help you with this like so

```
some_object_table = SomeObject.arel_table
SomeObject.where(some_object_table[property.intern].gt(value))
```

This will execute the query appropriately with all the escaping you have come to love with rails.

This works because `arel` is the underlying query assembler used by rails so `ActiveRecord` where clauses can understand `Arel::Nodes` without issue (its actually how they are assembled to begin with)

Also given the dynamic nature you may want to check that `property` is a valid column to avoid SQL level errors something like

```
raise AgrumentError unless some_object_table.engine.columns.map {|c| c.name.intern}.include?(property.intern)
# or 
raise AgrumentError unless SomeObject.column_names.map(&:to_sym).include?(property.to_sym)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ended by using

[ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_table_name](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/quoted_table_name/class) function to sanitize the column name before queries.

```
property = 'foo'
value = 'bar'

sanitized_property = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_table_name(property)
SomeObject.where("#{sanitized_property} > ?", value)
```

that function can handle table and column name definition.

property = 'table.column'

will produce

```
where `table`.`column` > `bar`
```